# spammers in magento website

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

We are facing huge online customers issue but with same Ip address which is consuming our huge CPU usage on server.

We are already installed **mage firewall** but we have to manually block the IP's while going to blacklist. 
Is there any way through which we can save CPU usage due to spam users, hackers which is throwing traffic which is not relevant for website?

We have already enabled Magento cache and **Full page cache** extension in Magento.

What more we can do so that we can protect our Magento website from vulnerability traffic effects and our CPU usage saves for other processes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a website and ecommerce management question placed in a programming section. Perhaps you want to move this over to http://magento.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

No real solution, but some things that have propably to be considered:

First, I would check, what defines a spammer in your case. 
How many times does the spammer do a certain action? Does he follow a special interaction pattern?

If the user is doing an action `y`, which is known to be done by spammers, for the first time, you could start to track the repeating action `y`. After `x`-times you could block the user.

The difficulty here is to find a difference in the using pattern between a spammer and a regular user, who is propably just doing things fast.

The reason why you should find a spammer-pattern is that this way you don't need to save every user's IP-address. Sure, you could do this, so that you don't need to find a pattern anymore and you just need to check how often the IP-adress is interacting. But this will fill up the database pretty fast.

By tracking and saving I am talking about storing the user-IP in a database. So you see that you have to find a way to store a miminum of false positives (good users), 0 at best, in the database. Otherwise you have good users who get blacklisted for no reason.

Maybe the way with the least implementation effort and with the minimum risk is keeping it the way it is, and blacklisting spammers manually. This on the other hand is an effort for you.

Comment: Any extension which can help to block these spammers ip's because they are increasing server load day by day.